# Nexus 7 does not goes past ubuntu boot up screen!

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

**Installing ubuntu on my Nexus 7.**

PC showed success message and then I waited for few minutes some white text and then boom.. *ubuntu logo*.

After that the device went blank... now when I boot I see Google Logo and after that ubuntu logo with white and red dots and then nothing happens.

again blank.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. The phone boots (showing the Google splash briefly) then nothing.